Updating and inserting from source to target table when MERGE ... USING approach seems too slow
I have a seemingly simple query that takes about 7 minutes to execute in a local SQL Server Express and about 40 minutes on Azure in a production SQL Server.
The source table has about 1 million rows, the target has 10 million and is growing slowly. Unfortunately, the source table has duplicates and that's why GROUP BY was added.
The query execution plan shows that it has a few heavy Sort operators that cause spilling to tempdb even locally, so I imagine it would be spilling on Azure even more.
As there are so many columns involved in grouping and the merge condition, I'm afraid that there's no use of indexes here, as I would have to index almost all the columns.
What would be a better solution to achieve the same results of inserting unique records from the source table into the target table when they differ and only updating the target timestamp when both sides match?
MERGE TargetTable AS target
USING (SELECT
           [Name], [CategoryName],
           [Field01], [Field02], [Field03], [Field04], [Field05],
           [Field06], [Field07], [Field08], [Field09], [Field10],
           [Value], [StartDate], [EndDate]
       FROM 
           SourceTable
       GROUP BY
           [Name], [CategoryName], 
           [Field01], [Field02], [Field03], [Field04], [Field05],
           [Field06], [Field07], [Field08], [Field09], [Field10],
           [Value], [StartDate], [EndDate]) 
    AS source ([Name], [CategoryName], 
               [Field01], [Field02], [Field03], [Field04], [Field05],
               [Field06], [Field07], [Field08], [Field09], [Field10],
               [Value], [StartDate], [EndDate])
        ON (target.[Name]           = source.[Name] AND
            target.[CategoryName]   = source.[CategoryName] AND
            target.[Field01]        = source.[Field01] AND
            target.[Field02]        = source.[Field02] AND
            target.[Field03]        = source.[Field03] AND
            UPPER(target.[Field04]) = source.[Field04] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND
            UPPER(target.[Field05]) = source.[Field05] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND
            UPPER(target.[Field06]) = source.[Field06] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND
            target.[Value]          = source.[Value] AND
            target.[StartDate]      = source.[StartDate] AND
            target.[EndDate]        = source.[EndDate])  

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET [UpdatedDateTime] = GETUTCDATE()
                       
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT ([Name], [CategoryName],
            [Field01], [Field02], [Field03], [Field04], [Field05],
            [Field06], [Field07], [Field08], [Field09], [Field10],
            [Value], [StartDate], [EndDate], [UpdatedDateTime])
    VALUES
        (source.[Name], source.[CategoryName],
         source.[Field01], source.[Field02], source.[Field03], source.[Field04], source.[Field05],
         source.[Field06], source.[Field07], source.[Field08], source.[Field09], source.[Field10],
         source.[Value], source.[StartDate], source.[EndDate], GETUTCDATE());


Obligatory: https://sqlblog.org/merge - there are links there that explain why performance isn't the only reason you should avoid MERGE and also links that show you optimal UPSERT patterns.

UPPER(target.[Field04]) = source.[Field04] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS has a smell. Why are you source and destination tables in different collations? Also as your column Field04 is in a case sensitive collation, then surely changing the different case characters are important, so why do you use UPPER?

@ThomA Good question. That's a legacy query that I'm trying to sort out. The default DB collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. So maybe the logic was there that the uppercased version of the target must match the source, but only if it was uppercase initially. Looks fishy, anyway.

@AaronBertrand  Thank you for the warnings. I'll try using two queries with EXISTS and NOT EXISTS instead.

Is there no primary key on either table? Do you really need to join on so many columns?

@Charlieface Unfortunately yes, the data initially is loaded from an old external API without any sensible keys. So locally we have only IDENTITY, which means nothing in the business sense, and we have to compare all columns to detect the changes.

You could create some hash field on both source and target, index it and join on that. Also, i don't get your group by, you will still crash the merge if there's duplicate on the "key" fields. I'd probably filter out duplicates ahead of merge
